# What is the number of subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$ that contain at least one of any two consecutive elements?

Tags: combinatorics

This is a weird question. I don't really understand the "at least one of two consecutive elements" part. I think those are such sets:

$\{1,3,5,7,9\}, \{2,4,6,8,10\}, \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$

Are there any other subsets like these?

Comment: I think it means subsets which has at least one pair of integers who differ by one : e.g. : $\{1,2,4,6,8,10\}$. I think you should look for the number of complement subsets than subtract $2^n$ (all number of subsets) by it.

Comment: Then how do I find the number of complement subsets?

Comment: Complement subsets are those who doesn't contain any two consecutive elements. My knowledge is not enough to help you!

Comment: That interpretation seems implausible to me. I would read the kind of set we're looking for as one which intersects every pair $\{k-1,k\}$ where $2\leq k\leq n$. I think this is what the OP was thinking.

Comment: The wording in your title is different from that in the question body. Which one reflects the problem as it was stated to you?

Comment: More generally, titles are for a title. Please make the question body self-contained.

Comment: @Kevin The actual question is in the title and my thoughts are in the question body

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Every subset of $[n]$ that fulfills your criteria must have either $n-1$ or $n$ as it's largest element.

**Hint:** How would you create a subset of $[n+1]$? What can you say about the largest element?

**Hint** Let $G_n$ be the answer. Use the above to show that $G_{n+1} = G_n + G_{n-1}$.

> Consider any valid subset, and split it according to the largest element in the subset.
> If the largest element is $n+1$, then ignoring this element, we have a valid subset for $G_n$.
> If the largest element is $n$, then ignoring this element, we have a valid subset for $G_{n-1}$.
> Hence $G_{n+1} = G_{n} + G_{n-1}$

Comment: @user14111 Nope, you are correct. I wrote too hastily. I've added in the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other examples of subsets of $\{1,...,10\}$ containing one of any two consecutive elements: $\{1,2,3,5,6,8,10\},\{2,4,6,7,9\}$. Another way to think of these sets is as those with no gaps bigger than $1$. This interpretation may help you begin to count them: either $1$ or $2$ is in the set, and if $k$ is in then either $k+1$ or $k+2$ must be, so you can define a set by the differences between its consecutive elements.

Answer (score 1):

The sets you want to count correspond to sequences of $n$ zeros and ones that don't contain two consecutive zeros.  The counts are given by the Fibonacci numbers; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number specifically the first bullet item under "Occurrences in Mathematics" (and interchange the roles of $0$ and $1$)>